# What is wrong with this exercise block?

Tags: jquery

I know by now that no matter how convinced I am that my code is right-- it's not-- if it won't work. My code from tutorial http://youtu.be/ydchsJYj_Mg doesn't work. "Welcom..." supposed to fadeIn. Spent much time checking it. Requesting your help please.

```
<!DOCUMENT HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ex: 3</title>
<style>
p{
cursor:pointer
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="message" style="display:none;">Welcome to my website</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_jQuery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#message').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Is init.js located in the same directory as your html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jquery first, not after your script.

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_jQuery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Stunned to learn that "order of appearance" matters. Will be mindful of it from now on. Thank you very much.